# Get matched data out of re2 Arg

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I'm trying to use re2 but couldn't see how I get the matched data out of the RE2::Arg[] when the number of matches in the regex are determined at run time.

I have something like this:

```
const RE2::Arg *args[10] = {};
int n = 0;
if (RE2::ConsumeN(_content.get(), rule.first, args, n)) {
  int consumed = _content->data() - start;
  //...stuff
}
```

If my regex is "(foo)|(bar)" args[0] and args[1] should be foo and bar respectively right?

How do I get the matched string from args[0] and so on...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC RE2::ConsumeN modifies its first argument, so you can call in the loop to get subsequent matches.

Try something like this:

```
RE2::StringPiece input(_content.get());

while (RE2::ConsumeN(&input, rule.first, args, n)) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

See also FindAndConsumeN if you are **searching** for matches, rather than matching prefixes.